# Euler - Operator Splitting for $y'+y=3e^2t$, $y(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

$y'+y=3e^2t$, $y(0)=1$

How can we solve this equation with operator splitting methods in matlab by using forward Euler method?

Comment: What do you want to split? The solution of the part linear in `y` is the integrating factor `exp(t)`, so set y(t)=u(t)*exp(t)` as usual.

Answer (score 1):

$${ y }^{ \prime  }+y=3{ e }^{ 2t }\\ \\ { y }^{ \prime  }+y=0\\ { y }^{ \prime  }=-y\\ \int { \frac { dy }{ y }  } =-\int { dt } \\ \ln { y } =-t+C\\ y=C{ e }^{ -t }\\ y=C\left( t \right) { e }^{ -t }\\ { y }^{ \prime  }={ C }^{ \prime  }\left( t \right) { e }^{ -t }-C\left( t \right) { e }^{ -t }\\ { C }^{ \prime  }\left( t \right) { e }^{ -t }-C\left( t \right) { e }^{ -t }+C\left( t \right) { e }^{ -t }=3{ e }^{ 2t }\\ { C }^{ \prime  }\left( t \right) { e }^{ -t }=3{ e }^{ 2t }\\ { C }^{ \prime  }\left( t \right) =3{ e }^{ 3t }\\ C\left( t \right) =\int { 3{ e }^{ 3t } } dt={ e }^{ 3t }+{ C }_{ 1 }\\ y={ e }^{ -t }\left( { e }^{ 3t }+{ C }_{ 1 } \right) $$
and consider the condition that $y\left( 0 \right) =1$ $$y\left( 0 \right) =1+C=1\\ C=0$$ so the final answer is

> $$y={ e }^{ 2t } $$

Comment: thank you so much :) but  how this solution write in matlab by using forward euler?

Comment: you are welcome, @ElifHacısalihoğlu,but unfortunately i don't what "operator splitting methods in matlab by using forward euler method" is